# How to remove LSP <header-line>?

Tags: lsp-mode, lsp, header-line

I'm pretty much emacs noob. I've been tinkering in spacemacs for around a month now and got it set up pretty much how I like it. But since I updated it, header line that appears when I open a project using projectile became extra tall:
[image]

I've been trying to find a way to either remove it, or make it take a less space horizontally, but hadn't had any success. Can anybody help?

**EDIT:**

So after doing some changes with layers, I figured out that that "header-line" is actually coming from pyright (LSP backend for python).

**UPDATE:**

Adding `(setq lsp-headerline-breadcrumb-enable nil)` to user config hides that header line.

Comment: Is the `header-line-format` enabled in the offending buffer using a default / stock installation of `spacemacs` without any modifications?  You may wish to `grep` your `spacemacs` source code installation for `header-line-format` and then determine the best way to disable that for the offending buffer.  You mentioned `projectile`, so I pulled that up and word-searched it, but there is no setting of the `header-line-format` therein ... https://github.com/bbatsov/projectile/blob/master/projectile.el

Comment: @Rasko "UPDATE" section worked for me. I guess the author can just extract it as an explicit answer and accept

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I disable lsp-headerline?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/64970/how-can-i-disable-lsp-headerline)

Comment: It's a shame that answers were given to the later duplicate to this question, and no answers were provided to this one, which was first. Unfortunately, duplicate-closing is limited to questions with no upvoted answers etc. Things would be much better if both those posing questions and those answering them checked first for an existing duplicate. In this case, the question title is almost exactly the same.

Comment: OP: If you had posted your "update" text as an *answer* then there would likely be no duplicate question created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `(setq lsp-headerline-breadcrumb-enable nil)` to user config hides that header line.