# How can I disable lsp-headerline?

Tags: lsp-mode, lsp, header-line

I'm using centaur tabs, and when lsp-headerline enables my tabs hides. I want to disable that headerline using `lsp-headerline-bradcrumb-mode` in a hook

```lisp
(use-package lsp-mode
  :commands (lsp lsp-deferred)
  :init
  (setq lsp-keymap-prefix "C-c l")
  :config
  (lsp-enable-which-key-integration t)
  :hook
  (lsp-mode . lsp-headerline-breadcrumb-mode)
)
```

Something like this. But it does not work. also I tryed to set `lsp-headerline-breadcrumb-enable` to nil in the config of my plugin, but it gives me an error `lsp-headerline-breadcrumb-enable is not defined`

EDIT: Other possible fix to this issue is find a way to keep visible and functional my tabs if it not possible to hide the bradcrumb.

Note: In the breadcrumb after the file name it says *invalid* [image]

Comment: Setting `(setq lsp-headerline-breadcrumb-enable nil)` after `lsp-mode` has been loaded should work. Please check whether your installation is correct.

Comment: As Lorem Ipsum says it looks like a bug, mi installation is right, is a fresh install

Comment: It's a shame that an answer was given to this *duplicate question*, and no answers were provided to the question this one duplicates. Unfortunately, duplicate-closing is limited to questions with no upvoted answers etc. Things would be much better if both those posing questions and those answering them checked first for an existing duplicate. In this case, the question title is almost exactly the same: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/63000/105 (*"How to remove LSP <header-line>?"*). Searching for tag `[header-line]` showed it immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed lsp-mode package and reinstaled, after that I can use (setq lsp-headerline-breadcrumb-enable nil) and everything works fine now, thanks to Lorem Ipsum for the help.

```lisp
(use-package lsp-mode
  :commands (lsp lsp-deferred)
  :init
  (setq lsp-keymap-prefix "C-c l")
  :config
  (setq lsp-headerline-breadcrumb-enable nil)
  (lsp-enable-which-key-integration t)
  ;;(lsp-mode . pao/lsp-mode-setup))
)
```

Comment: Absolutely!  Looks like you got some help from the main source (https://github.com/emacs-lsp/lsp-mode/issues/2525).  Thanks for your efforts!

Answer (score 1):

There appears to be [a bug in `lsp-mode`](https://github.com/emacs-lsp/lsp-mode/issues/2525) which causes `lsp-headerline-breadcrumb-enable` to not work as expected.

I believe the following workaround should result in the desired behavior (no breadcrumb):

```lisp
(add-hook 'lsp-mode-hook #'lsp-headerline-breadcrumb-mode)
```

This will call `lsp-headerline-breadcrumb-mode` each time `lsp` mode is enabled.  Because of the breadcrumb bug, I believe breadcrumbs are enabled by default (regardless of `lsp-headerline-breadcrumbe-enable`'s value).  Calling breadcrumb mode should therefore disable breadcrumbs.  There are many other `lsp` hooks to use if this one isn't ideal.

Comment: It look like it is working when I first open a file, but, after the LSP server is loaded the bradcrumb is enabled again, how can I hook the ``lsp-headerline-breadcrumb-enable`` to that event?

Comment: I'm experiencing similar behavior.  There are several other hooks that lsp provides.  I'm not sure which one is the one we need.  Check `C-h v lsp--hook TAB` to see a listing of all the available hooks.  I'll have to experiment more later.

Comment: I checked ``lsp-after-initialize-hook`` and it is what I need, I tested it opening treemacs after the language server loads, but for some reason ``lsp-headerline-bradcrumb-mode`` does nothing.

Other possible fix to my problem is show the breadcrumb and my tabs.

Answer (score 0):

This seemed to work for me. I don't use `use-package` and the other `lsp-mode-hook` answer wasn't working.

```
(add-hook 'lsp-mode-hook
  (lambda()
    ;;; other stuff...
    (setq lsp-headerline-breadcrumb-enable nil)))
```